# Animation from within DataTemplate

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Below is the data template I'm using for a listbox's ItemTemplate.  It shows some simple data, and a button, which ideally should animate a Popup, also contained within the DataTemplate.  Unfortunately the whole thing blow up at runtime.  The error says line 52 is wrong, which is:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
```

Here's the whole DataTemplate.  I've used this popup before, with the same exact content templates and even the same animation elsewhere.  It's only blowing up when I try to put it into a DataTemplate.  I assume the animation is having difficulty finding the right animation target - I'm hoping someone here would know more.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate2">
        <Border Width="100" Height="100" BorderThickness="4" BorderBrush="Red">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}"/>
                <Popup x:Name="popupContent" IsOpen="True" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" >
                    <Popup.Child>
                        <Thumb x:Name="thumbContent" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" Width="0" Height="0">
                            <Thumb.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <local:thumbTemplate Margin="0" x:Name="df" />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Thumb.Template>
                        </Thumb>
                    </Popup.Child>
                </Popup>
                <Button Content="Show">
                    <Button.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                                    <Storyboard x:Name="sbShowPopup">
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="200" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="popupContent" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="80" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="popupContent" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Button.Triggers>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have used this before but not in Silverlight.  The only supported value for `RoutedEvent` in Silverlight is "FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent".

You will need the BlendSDK to do this sort of thing in Silverlight.

Comment: Huh - I tried duplicating this in a more simple situation in the hopes of proving you wrong, but it appears as though you're right.  Thank you for the response.